# Two equal Time objects are not equal according to ==

Tags: ruby

I've found some behaviour of `Time` in Ruby that I don't understand while writing some tests. Am I missing something or is this a genuine problem?

I can reproduce the situation in irb as follows - first create a `Time` and add 30 seconds to it:

```
t = Time.new(2007,01,15,11,15,30.1)
# => 2007-01-15 11:15:30 +0000 
t1 = t + 30
# => 2007-01-15 11:16:00 +0000
```

Then create another time which should be equal to `t1`:

```
t2 = Time.new(2007,01,15,11,16,0.1)
# => 2007-01-15 11:16:00 +0000
```

Now I'd expect `t1` and `t2` to be equal, but they aren't according to `==`. From the rough experiments I've done it seems like `==` works, except when the addition of seconds moves `t1` onto a new minute:

```
t1 == t2
# => false
```

However if you call `to_f` on them then `==` does return `true`:

```
t1.to_f == t2.to_f
# => true
```

Just to confirm that there aren't any nano seconds hanging around:

```
t1.nsec
# => 100000000 
t2.nsec
# => 100000000
```

=== Added after answers from joanbm and Vitalii Elenhaupt (sorry to open this up again)

joanbm and Vitalii Elenhaupt point out that `t1.to_r` and `t2.to_r` produce different results.

But... according to the [Ruby-Doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html) `Time` within the normal range is stored as a 63 bit integer of the number of nano seconds since the epoch - which suggests that float-point issues shouldn't come into it.

So... why if Time is stored as an integer, and `#to_f` and `#nsec` can produce the same result to 9 decimal places, can't `==` use this info to recognize the two times as equal? (Maybe Ruby uses `#to_r` in the equality test?).

And... is it safe to assume that `t1.to_f == t2.to_f` will always give an accurate test of equality to 9 decimal places and is that the best way to compare `Time` objects?

Comment: According to `t1 <=> t2`, t1 is somehow greater than t2. No idea how...

Answer (score 5):

This is the [notorious](http://floating-point-gui.de/) problem with inaccurate representation of floating point numbers in computers, quite unrelated to Ruby or Time class implementation.

You give to both objects floating numbers as seconds argument, and its (inaccurate) fractional part constructor stores as a rational number for its internal representation:

```
t = Time.new(2007,01,15,11,15,30.1)
t.subsec    # (14073748835533/140737488355328)  <- may vary on your system
t.subsec.to_f    # 0.10000000000000142  <- this is not equal to 0.1 !!
```

dtto for the 2nd time:

```
t2 = Time.new(2007,01,15,11,16,0.1)
t2.subsec    # (3602879701896397/36028797018963968)
t2.subsec.to_f  # 0.1 <- there accidentally precision didn't get lost
```

Just use exact numerical types like `Rational` and you are done:

```
t = Time.new(2007,01,15,11,15,Rational('30.1'))
t1 = t + 30

t2=Time.new(2007,01,15,11,16,0.1r)  # alternate notation, see docs

t1 == t2    # true
```

Or do a rough comparison with `Time#round` method applied on both sides.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. My only question about you answer is that you say "give both objects floating point numbers as UTC offsets" but the 5th param in `Time.new` is seconds I think?

Answer (score 0):

You are using different parameters for your Time objects

```
#irb
t = Time.new(2007,01,15,11,15,30,0.1)
=> 2007-01-15 11:15:30 +0000
t1 = t2 + 30
=> 2007-01-15 11:16:00 +0000
```

if you do not pass the minutes, on my system the timezone seems to change:

```
t2 = Time.new(2007,01,15,11,16,0.1)
=> 2007-01-15 11:16:00 +0100 # what happened here? '+0100'

t1 == t2
=> false
```

Even if that is *not the case* for the op, it is interesting that this happens in my irb.
Building the objects like so `Time.utc(2007,01,15,11,15,30,0.1)`, using an explicit time zone, returned exactly the behaviour you described.

However, if you pass the *same amount of parameters* (0 minutes for t2) the comparison will return the expected result as you will probably not even run into the floating point problem described by joanbm.

```
t = Time.new(2007,01,15,11,15,30,0.1)
=> 2007-01-15 11:15:30 +0000 

t1 = t + 30
=> 2007-01-15 11:16:00 +0000 

t2 = Time.new(2007,01,15,11,16,0,0.1)
=> 2007-01-15 11:16:00 +0000 

t1 == t2
=> true
```

If you print the times rational form you get:

```
t1.to_r
=> (42112611033072059383231283/36028797018963968) 
t2.to_r
=> (42112611033072059383231283/36028797018963968)
```

As `to_r` returns the time in seconds since the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) (or Unix Time), there is no reason for t1 and t2 not to be equal, as long as date, time and time zone match.

Unfortunately I can not give a good explenation why this is the case.
This seems interesting though and I will come back when I find a reason for this behaviour.

**Edit**

This does not explain the timezone change, hence does not explain the problem, but your are missing a comma for `t` so you're actually passing 30.1 instead of 30 seconds.

```
t = Time.new(2007,01,15,11,15,30.1)
```

It probably should be

```
t = Time.new(2007,01,15,11,15,30,0.1)
```

However this does not cause your comparison to fail.

Comment: I don't think I'm getting a changed timezone - I'm getting +00:00 all the way through.

Comment: Try passing 0 seconds as an additional parameter to t2 so both time objects are built the same way, as I did above. The equal comparison will return true as expected.

Comment: It's intentional to pass 30.1 as I want have a time with fractional seconds -  the parameter after seconds isn't subseconds, it's timezone offset.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because both times are still different. Here is a good illustration with [Time#to_r](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-i-to_r):

```
>> t1.to_r #=> (164501373566169071275213/140737488355328)
>> t2.to_r #=> (42112351632939282246454477/36028797018963968)
```

If you don’t care about milliseconds, you may compare timestamps using `to_i` method:

```
>> t1.to_i == t2.to_i # => true
```

or make a new `Time` object from timestamps:

```
>> Time.at(t1.to_i) == Time.at(t2.to_i) # => true
```

Comment: Actually timestamps are a common a source for mistakes when compared, especially using the `==` operator. t1 and t2 can and should be identical objects when built the same way. Somehow ruby seems to change the time zone, with the given parameters.

Comment: OPs timezone is the same for `t1` and `t2` (`+0000`)